# Firestore Cloud Messaging Error - "Request contains an invalid argument" when trying to send Notification to a user

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I launch my application (Xcode/Swift), I can obtain the `FCMToken` for the user and store it in Firestore.

[image]

Then, when I invite someone to a game, the cloud function retrieves the `UID` of the invited players to find their document and retrieve the `FCMToken` from Firestore.

The cloud function modifies data in Firestore as desired, as you can see it adds the gameID to the "invites" array. However, the message cannot be sent to the user to notify them that they have been invited.

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendInviteNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("lobby/{lobbyId}")
    .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
      // Obtain the list of invited players before and after the update
      const oldInvitedPlayers = change.before.data().invited_players;
      const newInvitedPlayers = change.after.data().invited_players;
      // Check if any players have been added
      const addedPlayers = newInvitedPlayers
          .filter((player) => !oldInvitedPlayers || !oldInvitedPlayers
              .includes(player));

      // If there are no new players, stop the function here
      if (addedPlayers.length === 0) return null;

      // For each added player, add the lobbyID to their invites array
      for (const playerId of addedPlayers) {
        // Get the user document
        const playerDocRef = admin.firestore().collection("users")
            .doc(playerId);
        const playerDoc = await playerDocRef.get();
        const playerInvites = playerDoc.data().invites || [];
        try {
          // Add the lobbyID to the user's invites array
          playerInvites.push(context.params.lobbyId);

          // Update the invites array in the user document
          await playerDocRef.update({
            invites: playerInvites,
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error updating user invites:", error);
          return null; // Stop execution in case of error
        }

        // Get the FCM token of the player
        const playerToken = playerDoc.data().fcmToken;
        // Prepare the notification
        const message = {
          notification: {
            title: "Nouvelle invitation",
            body: "Vous avez ete invite a rejoindre un lobby",
          },
          token: playerToken,
        };
        try {
          // Send the notification
          await admin.messaging().send(message);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error sending message:", error.message);
          console.error("Error sending message:", error);
          console.error("Full error object:", JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
          console.log("Message affiche :", JSON.stringify(message, null, 2));
          return null; // Stop execution in case of error
        }
      }

      return null;
    });
```

here is the error :

[image]

Do you have any idea to help me ?